# JMeter - Store/update a hashmap object in a variable/property

Tags: java, hashmap, jmeter, jms, jsr223

I need to create a hash-map inside of a `JSR233 sampler` that will contain certain headers and properties elements for an external java utility that I will call using a `Java Request Sampler`. I am going to need to create many hashmaps as the key-value pairs will vary based on the systems I am testing. For example, I am going to have to change the `JMSReplyTo`, the `JMSCorrelationID`, `$TextBody:` fields for every hash-map. All of this is done inside **one** thread group, but I may also want to implement it in other thread groups down the road.

> How should I structure my Test Plan? Is it possible to create a global variable that will hold the hash-map? And then inside the respective `JSR223 Sampler`, for each test, modify the value of the variable?

I don't know when to use **properties** and when to use **variables**. In this case I would like `1` var or property that will change throughout my test-plan whenever I create a new hash-map object. I would like to know if this route is feasible, or if an alternative is advised.

The reason I would like to create a HashMap object in JMeter is because I don't want to have thousands of txt files that the Java utility will read and parse for the key-value pairs (those values vary in **every** txt file).

> Instead I was wondering if there was a way to create this HashMap
>   object in Jmeter and store it in a variable/property object that can
>   be passed as a **parameter** in my `Java Request`.

I would appreciate it if someone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: what about store it in a csv and use a CSVDtasetConfig? You stor your key pair as csv, and the configelement rotate giving a row for each thread

Comment: I should elaborate more: I am trying to avoid having multiple text files that the Java utility will have to read and parse. Instead of having 1000s of text messages with key:value pairs, I would like to set the key-value pairs in Jmeter instead. And then pass an object of type HashMap to this Java Utility using the Java Request.

Comment: the csv is handled by jemter itself. what you mean exactly when you say inside jmeter?

Comment: Right, so inside a script like JSR233 I create a HashMap object and use its "put" function to populate the hash-map for that particular test. Then I want to pass this hash-map object as a parameter in my Java Request Sampler. However this is only for one scenario; I will have many more, where I will have to construct another hash-map with different key-value pairs that I want to pass to the Java Request as parameters. I am thinking the following structure: Transaction Controller - JSR223 Sampler - Java Request

Comment: so, if I am right: you want to test your java utility, to do that you need to configure it for the right system. your JSR233 does not exist in nature, and you use only to pass paramenter (your HashMap) to the utility. the hashmap is always the same  for the same system, and it will be different for another system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using regular get put operations

```
 vars.get("map"); vars.put("map", map);
```

You can use get put operations on Objects other than string:

```
 vars.putObject("map", map);
```

And get map later:

```
 map = vars.getObject("map");
```

Comment: Would I be able to use vars.getObject("map") inside the Java Request, under the values field?

Answer (score 1):

1. JMeter Variables are local to each JMeter Thread, cannot be shared between different Thread Groups. Used to hold user-specific values. Can be accessed as `vars` from JSR223 Elements, see [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) for all available methods and fields.
2. [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) are "normal" [Java properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), they are global for the whole [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) and can be accessed from any Thread in any Thread Group.

Assuming the above if you have many user-specific HashMaps - go for JMeter Variables. If you have one global HashMap and/or you need to access it from different Thread Groups - go for properties.