# Can we assert API response using code like javascript using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to explore Jmeter for API testing.

I am able to add Assert using response assertion of Jmeter.

But I like a platform in Jmeter where we can write our code to assert more complex scenario of testing API tests on API.

Similar as we can say we do use of groovy scripts in SOAP-UI or javascript in postman tests using Newman node module.

Is it possible in Jmeter?

Is there any plug-in available to achieve same in Jmeter.

I have tried to found out any tutorial or blog regarding same but land with no success.

If anyone has tried then please do share your experience, way, blog or tutorials which can lead me to achieve same in Jmeter that would really help.

Any workaround will be helpful and appreciated in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can execute Javascript (on server side) to assert API response

You just need to add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a Assertion to your request and choose Language as `javascript` and write your assertion code by checking `prev` which is a [SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

Here a demo that get response search for string `success` and log the first position in string using javascript:

```
var response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
var pos = response.search("success");
log.info(pos);
```

Comment: thats great can you please share sample code or blog which leads me an idea that how to achieve same

Comment: Thanks it is move me ahead for my current task. can you suggest a better way to assert in same. means in Jmeter which can also refect on report

Comment: Is it possible to have an example that actually asserts something? Or maybe just a link to the reference in Javascript? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

continuing the user7294900 answer you can write code something like below in JSR223 Assertion:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var responseBody = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
log.info(responseBody)
log.info(responseBody.code)

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
log.info("my name from response = "+jsonData.name)
```

I have found Jmeter have inbuild function of Assert that is **AssertionResult**

**Groovy**

Use code as below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    failureMessage += "Invalid JSON.\n"
}

log.info("***********Starting Assert************")
log.info("******************************************************")
log.info("my name ="+jsonResponse.name)

if(!"201".equals(prev.getResponseCode())){
    failureMessage += "Expected <response code> [201] but we got instead [" + prev.getResponseCode() + "]\n\n" ;
}

if(!"morpheus".equals(jsonResponse.name)){
    failureMessage += "Expected name is morpheus but we got instead [" + jsonResponse.name + "]\n\n" ;
    log.info("asset fail")
}

if(!"morpheus2".equals(jsonResponse.name)){
    failureMessage += "Expected name is morpheus2 but we got instead  [" + jsonResponse.name + "]\n\n" ;
    log.info("asset fail")
}

if(!"leader".equals(jsonResponse.job)){
    failureMessage += "Expected job is leader but we got instead [" + jsonResponse.job + "]\n\n" ;
    log.info("asset fail")
}

if(!"leader1".equals(jsonResponse.job)){
    failureMessage += "Expected job is leader1 but we got instead [" + jsonResponse.job + "]\n\n" ;
    log.info("asset fail")
}

// Print error messages if any
if (failureMessage?.trim()) {
    failureMessage += "URL: " + SampleResult.getURL() + "\n\n";     
    failureMessage += "JSON RESPONSE: " + jsonResponse + "\n\n";
    failureMessage += "REQUEST HEADERS: " + SampleResult.getRequestHeaders() + "\n\n";

    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);    
}
```

Source:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial

Comment: AssertionResult isn't groovy's. it can be used in all languages including javascript

Comment: thats cool .. I will try it out for sure :) ... In a curisity can you please tell me how to set and get envt. variables in jmeter .. any workaround will be helpful

Comment: See answer and you can upvote if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696945/how-to-store-update-a-hashmap-object-in-a-variable-property-in-jmeter/45698016#45698016

Comment: You probably should open a new question with details

Comment: Sure .. give me 2 min

Comment: done .. see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441512/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-jmeter-to-test-apis

Answer (score 1):

The options are in:

1. [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) where you can use [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries in order to test the response
2. If you need more advanced logic you can go for [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and Groovy language. Groovy has [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you will be able to apply any custom logic. More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for sharing ... I will try it for sure .. i m out of office for now will try on Monday