# How to set and get environment variables in Jmeter to test API's

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I need to set and get variables in Jmeter for API automation.

I am using the groovy script for same.

I have achieved same using code as below:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

JMeterUtils.setProperty("PC_CREATED_PROMO_CODE", "shubhamvalue");

log.info("will it work? ="+JMeterUtils.getProperty("PC_CREATED_PROMO_CODE"))
```

Now the problem is I am not able to see the value in any contanier where I can set my hardcode values like token, baseURL, Headers. it should be similar we do in SOAP-UI or postman tests.

Please let me know if I can see these setProperty values in file/section/container in Jmeter.

Or suggest me any other workaround which is more feasible for same.

[image]

Any workaround will be helpful and appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get and set **variables** I would recommend using `vars` shorthand

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html.)

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads**, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So I would suggest setting variables as: `vars.put('foo', 'bar')` and accessing them as `${foo}` where required as my expectation is that you will be getting different `PC_CREATED_PROMO_CODE` for each thread (virtual user)

---

Also be aware that it is also recommended to avoid scripting where possible so consider going for [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) instead.

Comment: vars saves key-pair in which container.. means in property or User Defined Variables

Comment: additionally which container I should use for putting my variables .. property , user defined variables or any other option. variables needs to be updated time time as per script logic so what you will suggest in that case

Answer (score -1):

1) In JMeter GUI mode, under WorkBench, create Property Display by
WorkBench > Add > Non-Test Elements > Property Display.
Then select JMeter Properties checkbox to view all the exist properties

```
props.put("shubhamKey", "shubhamValue")
```

When you execute this code the property will set in a property file and you can see it in below location:

> WorkBench > Add > Non-Test Elements > Property Display.

2) Now if you are want to use User Defined Variables in your scripts you can call value like below:

```
vars.get("shubhamUserKey")
```

Still looking to set the value from code in User Defined Variables

Comment: You can set variable with property value as vars.put("shubhamKey",  props.get("shubhamUserKey"))

Comment: vars.put("shubhamUserKeyagain","shubhamUservalue") is not working to add values in  User Defined Variables

Comment: User Defined Variables is not the best way to update variables. please open a new question because it's too broad to answer here

Answer (score -1):

In JMeter, you can set and get environment variables using the built-in functions and properties. Environment variables in JMeter are often referred to as JMeter properties.

## Setting Environment Variables (Properties):

**1.Setting Variables in JMeter GUI:**

- Open your JMeter test plan in the JMeter GUI.
- Right click the test plan, then select Add > Config Element > User Defined Variables
- Add a new variable with the desired name and value.

**2.Setting Properties in JMeter Script:**

- You can set properties in your JMeter script using the __setProperty function. For example, to set a property named myVar with a value of 123:

```bash
${__setProperty(myVar, 123)}
```

- Place this in a BeanShell PreProcessor, JSR223 Sampler, or use it in a Beanshell assertion where needed.

## Getting Environment Variables (Properties):

**1.Getting Variables in JMeter GUI:**

- You can get the value of a variable in your JMete using `${variable_name}`

**2.Getting Properties in Beanshell or JSR223 Script:**

- In a Beanshell or JSR223 script, you can use the following to get the value:

```java
String myVarValue = props.get("myVar");
```

Comment: Environment variables are different from properties. Environment variables are set in the OS, or at the startup of JMeter. Environment variables can be read using the env function in the plugin "Custom JMeter Functions". I don't know how to do it in groovy, but I assume that there is a way there too.